# Links in tkinter text widget

Tags: python, tkinter, url, hyperlink

I'm making an app, and I'm using tkinter for the GUI.
My problem is that I need to recognize links in a Text widget and, when I click on some of them, open the website.
So I have this code:

```
def search_for_url(event):
    # Expresión regular para buscar patrones de URLs
    patron_url = re.compile(r"(http|https)://[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(/\S*)?")
    
    # Buscar patrones de URL en el texto
    for match in re.finditer(patron_url, chat_area.get("1.0", END)):
        inicio = "1.0+" + str(match.start()) + "c"
        fin = "1.0+" + str(match.end()) + "c"
        
        # Agregar etiqueta de enlace al patrón de URL encontrado
        chat_area.tag_add("url", inicio, fin)
        
        # Configurar el cursor como "mano" cuando el mouse pasa sobre el enlace
        chat_area.tag_bind("url", "<Enter>", lambda event: chat_area.config(cursor="hand2"))
        chat_area.tag_bind("url", "<Leave>", lambda event: chat_area.config(cursor=""))
        
        # Configurar el enlace
        url = match.group()
        chat_area.tag_bind("url", "<Button-1>", lambda event, url=url: open_url(url))
    
def open_url(url):
    webbrowser.open_new(url)
```

My code is working fine, but it just saves the last url detected.
I know that I can save all the urls in an array, but I don't know how to open a specific url depending on the url I click.
Can you help me?

I think I have to find a way to determine the url index depending on the position the click was made.

Comment: You keep making new bindings to the same tag. You should use a unique tag for every link.

Comment: Try looking at [How to create hyperlink in a Tkinter Text Widget?](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-create-hyperlink-in-a-tkinter-text-widget)

Comment: Thanks, Brayan. It works with your solution.